# curl through paramiko fails with 401, running manually succeeds

Tags: python, authentication, paramiko

I am working with a large number of linux devices that can only be reached from a jumphost. Each device has has a RESTful endpoint with some data that I need to perform some logic on. Due to limitations with the administration of the jumphost, the only way to perform these calls is by using paramiko and running the curl, then capturing stdout and stderr.

I've recently discovered that some of the devices return a 401 unauthorized status code. The calls are all made synchronously in the same order, and they're peppered through the batch of devices (ie. 1st is successful, 2nd fails, 3rd-6th successful, 7th and 8th fails, etc.) I've also manually run paramiko against one of the failed devices, and it still failed on my manual run. The mystery is that if I log into the jumphost and perform the curl directly in the console, it returns a 200 status.

Run with Paramiko:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> import re
>>>
>>> client = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> client.connect('192.168.1.10', username='jumpuser', password='jumppa$$')
>>> _, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('curl -v -X POST --user "us3rn4me:p4$$w0rd" https://host/api/endpoint')
>>>
>>> print("\nOut Message: {}\nStatus Code: {}".format(stdout, re.findall(HTTP.*(\d\d\d), stderr)[-1]))  ​

Out Message: no valid authentication method found
Status Code: 401
```

CLI run:

```
[jumpuser@192.168.1.10~]$ curl -X POST --user "us3rn4me:p4$$w0rd" https://host/api/endpoint
{
    "search_id": "12839123004810F52359SF"
}
```

I don't know enough about how paramiko works and how/if the endpoints can see the origination point, but the only thing I can think is that there is something on these particular devices that is blocking the call. Not sure where to begin to look. Has anyone ever experienced something like this before?

Comment: I think it's related to your shell and password. Normally for this I would use single quotes, to avoid the shell replacing $$. In Bash particularly, $$ is the PID of the bash process itself. So from your python, try `exec_command("curl ... 'user:pa$$' url")`

Comment: @Hitobat I've tested that as well. The fact that it works sporadically, and fails on the exact same devices every time seems to indicate something with how those particular devices are seeing the traffic, which is what puzzles me.

Comment: @Hitobat I'm potate, that was exactly the problem. Thanks!